# How to Find position of Ears, cheek and Head positon for IOS using CIFaceFeature

Tags: objective-c, avfoundation, cifacefeature

In my project I need to fine all parts of faces like eyes, mouth, nose, ears, cheek and head. By using `CIFaceFeature`, I can get Eyes position and Mouth Position.

How to find rest of parts position?

Answer (score 0):

CIFaceFeature is derived from and inspired by academic research work that generally gets poured into [openCV](http://openCV.org). So to go beyond CIFaceFeature, you will need to get to grips with the openCV libraries. OpenCV.org provides a C++ framework that runs on most platforms, including iOS.

In particular you will want to look at [object detection](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/objdetect/doc/objdetect.html), the [cascade classifier](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/objdetect/cascade_classifier/cascade_classifier.html#cascade-classifier) and [haartraining](http://note.sonots.com/SciSoftware/haartraining.html#t1a1f262).

Judging by your comments you would like a simpler solution. I suppose that you could invent a generic 'face' type, idealised from everyone to a single example. Then calculate the relationships - from all angles?. That's as I have suggested, substantially simplifying the need for training. But is there such a thing as a Platonic face that would work acceptably well? Why don't you experiment with a few simple full-face photos and some parameters extrapolated from the eyes and mouth. Good luck...

**update**
You really want to go with openCV... here is a [nice video to explain why...](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=fvwp&NR=1&v=V7UdYzCMKvw)

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way that we can use some general relative distance to find rest of parts in face.

Comment: @user1960389, see my update, i hope the video link persuades you!

Comment: CIDetector is not from OpenCV directly, it is ported from Polar Rose, acquired by Apple.